# Gstreamer to save a video in patches

Tags: python, gstreamer, framebuffer

Do anyone know a **gstreamer** command to save webcam video in **patches** based on **MB size**.

I need to record a webcam video and save it as a separate file when it reaches 100mb size.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for pipelines with multifilesink or even hlssink which would produce those files for you.

multifilesink does what you want but might be careless for keyframes so the beginning of the files might not be not playable and you would lose some footage if you start from that fragment. hlssink should take care of that but it works on a time basis, not file size. You could update multifilesink to care more about key-frames or make hlssink have options to fragment based on file size and not on duration for your particular use case.

Anyway, here are some sample pipelines to get you started (not sure of what's your input or your encoding/decoding needs):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc num-buffers=100000 is-live=true ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! multifilesink max-file-size=100000000 next-file=4 location=%05d.ts

gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc num-buffers=100000 is-live=true ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink target-duration=60 location=%05d.ts
```

You can start with those and change the source to whatever you use for your webcam. You might be able to output your webcam format directly to a muxer or you might have to transcode. Just make sure to use a streaming container format, such as mpeg2ts.

This is a guess of what the final pipeline could look like, feel free to change the encoder:

```
gst-launch-1.0 autovideosrc ! queue ! decodebin ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! multifilesink max-file-size=100000000 next-file=4 location=%05d.ts
```

If you need audio as well you need to add a second branch to it:

```
gst-launch-1.0 autovideosrc ! queue ! decodebin ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux name=m ! multifilesink max-file-size=100000000 next-file=4 location=%05d.ts autoaudiosrc ! queue ! avenc_mp2 ! m.
```